# Showing conservation of momentum for arbitrary pendulum trajectories

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws, calculus

Consider an isolated system of a pendulum driven by a motor, initially at rest. Conservation of momentum and angular momentum ordains that the center of mass and orientation cannot change in the inertial frame over the course of one full revolution, but I'm having a tough time showing this from forces alone for an arbitrary trajectory $\theta(t)$. Consider the change in position along one linear axis of the pendulum mass in the inertial frame over the course of one rotation spanning time $t_f$:

[image]

$$
\Delta x =
  \int_0^{t_f} {\int_0^t a_r\sin(\theta(\tau))+a_c\cos(\theta(\tau)) d\tau dt}\\
  = r\int_0^{t_f} {\int_0^t \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\sin(\theta(\tau))+
  \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2\cos(\theta(\tau)) d\tau} dt
$$

Some of my initial attempts at the calculus don't reveal an obvious reason why this should be 0. (I admit this may just be my shortcomings with calculus.) My only instinct was to extract integrals of $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}\cos(\theta(t))$ via by-parts and group, also using the fact that $\theta(t_f)-\theta(0)=2\pi$ by construction:

$$
\Delta x =
  r\int_0^{t_f} \left[
    \left[ \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\bigg\rvert_0^t\sin(\theta(0)) -
    \int_0^t \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}\cos(\theta(\tau))d\tau \right] +
    \int_0^t\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2\cos(\theta(\tau)) d\tau
  \right]
  dt\\
=
  r\int_0^{t_f} \left[
    {\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\bigg\rvert_0^t\sin(\theta(0)) -
    3\int_0^t \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}\cos(\theta(\tau))d\tau +
    \left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2\bigg\rvert_0^t\int_0^t \cos(\theta(\tau)) d\tau}
  \right]
  dt
$$

And that's as far as I get. To reiterate, while I know $\Delta x$ is 0 by momentum conservation, I'm a bit frustrated I can't show it for this seemingly simple example with arbitrary $\theta$. I appreciate any help with my attempt.

Comment: I don't think the "3" is supposed to be there... I am able to arrive at the same equation but without the "3".  I am still working on it.

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs If my signs are right, the 3 comes from the derivative of $\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)^2$ during the second by parts step, which yields a 2 multiplier, added to the same single term from the first by parts

Comment: Oh yes my apologies i was careless in that.  I'm figuring out a way to cancel out the last to terms rn.

Comment: For $L=\dfrac {1}{2}mℓ^{2}\left( \dfrac {d\varphi }{dt}\right) ^{2}$ you get with EL $\dfrac {d}{dt} \left( ml^{2}\dfrac {d\varphi }{dt}\right) =0$ so $\left( ml^{2}\dfrac {d\varphi }{dt}\right) =const$